# Using tail -f in /var/www/site.access.log

Tags: linux, bash, tail

I have been spending the last 30 mins debugging an issue where I was unable to verify that a 3rd party server was accessing my site.

I have the following command:

```
tail -f /var/log/mysite.pythonanywhere.com.access.log
```

And I didn't see any text being outputted in my console.

So it turns out, the 3rd party did visit my server, but the entry did not have a newline character hence the `tail -f` was not flushed immediately.

This is what is being added to the log:

```
103.7.30.108 - - [20/May/2016:06:23:20 +0000] "GET /wechat?signature=0a99723f6953778a5b86a167d03bb720ff703896&echostr=2566246727656931322&timestamp=1463725400&nonce=784777684 HTTP/1.1" 200 19 "-" "Mozilla/4.0" "
```

How can I use `tail -f` on `/var/www/access.log` and force every character to be flushed immediately?

Comment: They look like apache logs, definitely should have newlines between entries.

Answer (score 4):

#### Step 1

By default I/O is buffered.  You want to turn buffering off for `tail -f`.  To do that on linux, use `stdbuf`:

```
stdbuf -o0 tail -f /path/to/logfile
```

`-o0` tells `stdbuf` to make output unbuffered.

`stdbuf` is part of GNU coreutils and should be included with any recent linux distribution.

#### Step 2

You didn't mention what process is writing to your log file.  There is a chance that it buffers its output.  You may need to review its documentation and turn off its output buffering.

Comment: It's apache writing to the log file. Will look into that. Thanks. (Still seeing delay)